# How to select particular database using InfluxDB web user interface

Tags: influxdb

I am using InfluxDB and caught up with interesting situation. I have created around 20 plus instances of D.B. as shown below.

[image]

Now, some of the Database names are not showing as they are way down below in the drop down list. I did apply zoom in, reducing font size, giving name of database so that they can come up at the staring of the list, but these all are temporary solutions. Wondering how to scroll database list or select specific database using some InfluxDB command?

InfluxDB version i am using is V 1.2.2

Comment: jus like we have USE "databasename", do we have equivalent command at web UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do either of these:

- Issue a SHOW DATABASES query to gather the list of your databases
- Prefix with the database name, e.g.

  ```
  SELECT * from DATABASENAME..MEASUREMENTNAME
  ```

  to query a specific database